# why not insert a watch to the top level directory with auditctl?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, audit, acts-as-audited

With the man manual, I know some information about `auditctl`. But with the option `-w path`, I found some information as follow:

> Insert a watch for the file system object at path. You cannot insert a watch to the top level directory. This is prohibited  by  the  kernel. Wildcards  are  not  supported either and will generate a warning.

According to my understanding, I think the command `auditctl -w /`  could not insert a watch to the top level directory. But with my test in CentOS, I found that is OK?

The result test information:

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ sudo auditctl -w /
[centos@localhost ~]$ sudo auditctl -l
-w / -p rwxa
[centos@localhost ~]$ cd /
[centos@localhost /]$ pwd
/
[centos@localhost /]$ ll
total 24
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root    0 Mar 13 17:01 1
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    7 Mar 13 16:56 bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   4 root root 4096 Mar 13 17:15 boot
drwxr-xr-x.  20 root root 3320 Mar 14 02:15 dev
drwxr-xr-x. 142 root root 8192 Mar 14 02:14 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root   20 Mar 13 17:12 home
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    7 Mar 13 16:56 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    9 Mar 13 16:56 lib64 -> usr/lib64
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Nov  5 11:38 media
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root    0 Mar 13 21:40 mmm
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Nov  5 11:38 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root   16 Mar 13 17:08 opt
dr-xr-xr-x. 219 root root    0 Mar 14 02:14 proc
dr-xr-x---.   6 root root  234 Mar 13 11:53 root
drwxr-xr-x.  40 root root 1180 Mar 14 02:15 run
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    8 Mar 13 16:56 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Nov  5 11:38 srv
dr-xr-xr-x.  13 root root    0 Mar 14 02:14 sys
drwxrwxrwt.  42 root root 4096 Mar 14 04:04 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Mar 13 21:40 ttt
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root  155 Mar 13 16:56 usr
drwxr-xr-x.  21 root root 4096 Mar 14 02:14 var
[centos@localhost /]$ sudo mkdir alex
[centos@localhost /]$ sudo touch alexzl
[centos@localhost /]$ ll
total 24
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root    0 Mar 13 17:01 1
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Mar 14 04:17 alex
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root    0 Mar 14 04:17 alexzl
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    7 Mar 13 16:56 bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   4 root root 4096 Mar 13 17:15 boot
drwxr-xr-x.  20 root root 3320 Mar 14 02:15 dev
drwxr-xr-x. 142 root root 8192 Mar 14 02:14 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root   20 Mar 13 17:12 home
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    7 Mar 13 16:56 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    9 Mar 13 16:56 lib64 -> usr/lib64
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Nov  5 11:38 media
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root    0 Mar 13 21:40 mmm
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Nov  5 11:38 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root   16 Mar 13 17:08 opt
dr-xr-xr-x. 218 root root    0 Mar 14 02:14 proc
dr-xr-x---.   6 root root  234 Mar 13 11:53 root
drwxr-xr-x.  40 root root 1180 Mar 14 02:15 run
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    8 Mar 13 16:56 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Nov  5 11:38 srv
dr-xr-xr-x.  13 root root    0 Mar 14 02:14 sys
drwxrwxrwt.  42 root root 4096 Mar 14 04:04 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Mar 13 21:40 ttt
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root  155 Mar 13 16:56 usr
drwxr-xr-x.  21 root root 4096 Mar 14 02:14 var
[centos@localhost /]$ sudo  ausearch  -f /

.............
.............
time->Tue Mar 14 04:17:00 2017
type=PATH msg=audit(1489479420.957:1682): item=1 name="alex" objtype=CREATE
type=PATH msg=audit(1489479420.957:1682): item=0 name="/" inode=64 dev=fd:00 mode=040555 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:root_t:s0 objtype=PARENT
type=CWD msg=audit(1489479420.957:1682):  cwd="/"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1489479420.957:1682): arch=c000003e syscall=83 success=no exit=-13 a0=7ffeb030b435 a1=1ff a2=1ff a3=7ffeb030a370 items=2 ppid=3444 pid=5955 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts0 ses=1 comm="mkdir" exe="/usr/bin/mkdir" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)

.............

time->Tue Mar 14 04:17:39 2017
type=PATH msg=audit(1489479459.343:1915): item=1 name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" inode=33613563 dev=fd:00 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:ld_so_t:s0 objtype=NORMAL
type=PATH msg=audit(1489479459.343:1915): item=0 name="/usr/bin/sudo" inode=1461019 dev=fd:00 mode=0104111 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:sudo_exec_t:s0 objtype=NORMAL
type=CWD msg=audit(1489479459.343:1915):  cwd="/"
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1489479459.343:1915): argc=3 a0="sudo" a1="touch" a2="alexzl"
type=BPRM_FCAPS msg=audit(1489479459.343:1915): fver=0 fp=0000000000000000 fi=0000000000000000 fe=0 old_pp=0000000000000000 old_pi=0000000000000000 old_pe=0000000000000000 new_pp=0000001fffffffff new_pi=0000000000000000 new_pe=0000001fffffffff
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1489479459.343:1915): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=e21e00 a1=e99fb0 a2=e34670 a3=7ffe09a62fa0 items=2 ppid=3444 pid=5971 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts0 ses=1 comm="sudo" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
----
```

Why the man manual does not support insertion a watch to the top level directory, but the test is OK?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is that it limit  to insert a watch on the top level directory not the child directory or file. for example, if you want to insert a watch to root directory, it is prohibited, but it could add the watches to child directory and file at the same time.